# Return an integer with GLSL step function

Tags: opengl, glsl

The GLSL function `step` returns a float (either `0.0f` or `1.0f`) or vector of floats. Is there a way to have it return an integer instead? I'm trying to use it to offset an index (without introducing an `if` statement):

```
const int[8] constIndicies = int[](
   0,1,2,3,
   1,3,0,2);    
...
float ratioEdge = 17.0f;
float myFloatValue = 9.0f;

... constIndicies[4*step(ratioEdge, myFloat)] ...
```

But with it returning a float, that doesn't work. And casting it to an int seems wrong.

Comment: GLSL isn't Java; `new int[]` is not legitimate GLSL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a digging around, it would seem the closest equivalent of a `step` function that returns an `int` is in the constructors of scalars.

```
int myStepInt = int(myFloat > ratioEdge); // returns integer 1 or 0.
```

The above is an alternative to

```
int myStepInt = myFloat > ratioEdge ? 1 : 0;
```

Whether or not either of the above are more/less branchless than the built-in `step` function remains a mystery to me though.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is either to cast `step(ratioEdge, myFloat)` to an int.
`constIndicies[4*int(step(ratioEdge, myFloat))]`

EDIT:
In response to Rabbid76 I removed the round suggestion.

Comment: In this case [`round`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/round.xhtml) is useless, because the result of step is either 0.0 or 1.0. `round` won't change that and the return type of `round` is a floating point type too.